# Trouble filling MySQL table using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm am trying to convert a database I had as a txt file into a MySQL database. I found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp) tutorial and tried to follow it, but every time I run I get the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Pdf' in 'field list'
```

Here is the code I wrote

```
import shutil
import os

import mysql.connector 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  database="Book"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Books (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))")


if os.path.exists("/home/Me/Desktop/Books/INFO.txt"): 
  #Extract the data from the txt file
  f= open("/home/Me/Desktop/Books/INFO.txt","r")
  Lines = f.readlines()
  Items=[]
  for line in Lines:
    line=line.replace("\n","")
    Items_not_s=line.split(",")
    Items_not_s=tuple(Items_not_s)
    Items.append(Items_not_s)
 #Extracted the data from the txt file

  sql = "INSERT INTO Books (Name, Pdf, Image, DegradedImage, Tags, Extra) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"


  val = Items
  print(val[20])
  mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
  mydb.commit()

  print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.") 

else:
    print("no file")
```

An example for the values (val) I want to put in the table is:

```
[('geekychefcookbook', '/home/Me/Desktop/Books/Food/Quarto Cookbooks/geekychefcookbook/PDF/PDF.pdf', 'None', '/home/Me/Desktop/Books/Food/Quarto Cookbooks/geekychefcookbook/IMAGE/IMAGE_RE.jpg', 'None', 'None'),('wickedgoodburgers', '/home/piotr/Desktop/Books/Food/Quarto Cookbooks/wickedgoodburgers/PDF/PDF.pdf', 'None', '/home/piotr/Desktop/Books/Food/Quarto Cookbooks/wickedgoodburgers/IMAGE/IMAGE_RE.jpg', 'None', 'None')]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MYSQL table does not have columns named `Pdf, Image, DegradedImage, Tags, Extra` as you are trying to insert.

The only columns you have are `name` and `address`, as defined in this line:

`mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Books (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))")`

Add all the columns in this line (by separating them with commas after `address VARCHAR(255)` with their specific data types and then try to insert your rows from the text file.

Comment: Of course! Completely missed that. Thank you